# sdf version problems cause drcsim2.6 and gazebo1.8 to crash

Tags: gazebo-1.8, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've recently updated to drcsim 2.6 and gazebo 1.8, however when I attempt the command: roslaunch atlasutils atlasdrcvehiclefire_hose.launch

I receive the following warnings before it crashes:

Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/usr/share/drcsim-2.6/gazebomodels/environments/vrcfirehoselong/model.sdf]. Warning [Converter.cc:58] Version[1.3] to Version[1.4] Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files. $ gzsdf convert [sdffile] Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/usr/share/drcsim-2.6/gazebomodels/environments/vrcstandpipe/model.sdf]. Warning [Converter.cc:58] Version[1.3] to Version[1.4] Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files. $ gzsdf convert [sdffile] Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/usr/share/drcsim-2.6/gazebomodels/environments/vrcvalve/model.sdf]. Warning [Converter.cc:58] Version[1.3] to Version[1.4] Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files. $ gzsdf convert [sdffile] Warning [gazebo_main.cc:62] escalating to SIGKILL on client

I have attempted to use the command gzsdf convert /usr/share/drcsim-2.6/gazebomodels/environments/vrcfirehose_long/model.sdf etc.

and then rerunning the roslaunch command, but it gives the same warnings. I have checked other topics, but they cannot seem to solve it.

I have also attempted to amend it by redownloading the environment models by moving them to a temporary file.
sudo mv   /usr/share/drcsim-2.6/gazebo_models/environments /home/david/backup-drc/

with the resulting problem when I try roslaunch
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:331] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[atlas_robot_state_publisher-9]: started with pid [20942]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[multisense_sl_robot_state_publisher-10]: started with pid [20971]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[tf2_buffer_server-11]: started with pid [21014]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[multisense_sl/camera/stereo_proc-12]: started with pid [21039]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://drc_vehicle]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://drc_vehicle]
Error [parser.cc:544] Unable to find uri[model://drc_vehicle]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://vrc_firehose_long]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://vrc_firehose_long]
Error [parser.cc:544] Unable to find uri[model://vrc_firehose_long]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://vrc_standpipe]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://vrc_standpipe]
Error [parser.cc:544] Unable to find uri[model://vrc_standpipe]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://vrc_valve]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://vrc_valve]
Error [parser.cc:544] Unable to find uri[model://vrc_valve]Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:331] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[atlas_robot_state_publisher-9]: started with pid [20942]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[multisense_sl_robot_state_publisher-10]: started with pid [20971]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[tf2_buffer_server-11]: started with pid [21014]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[multisense_sl/camera/stereo_proc-12]: started with pid [21039]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://drc_vehicle]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://drc_vehicle]
Error [parser.cc:544] Unable to find uri[model://drc_vehicle]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://vrc_firehose_long]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://vrc_firehose_long]
Error [parser.cc:544] Unable to find uri[model://vrc_firehose_long]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://vrc_standpipe]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://vrc_standpipe]
Error [parser.cc:544] Unable to find uri[model://vrc_standpipe]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://vrc_valve]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:404] Unable to download model[model://vrc_valve]
Error [parser.cc:544] Unable to find uri[model://vrc_valve]

What else should I do to get gazbeo simulations working again?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3395/sdf-version-problems-cause-drcsim2.6-and-gazebo1.8-to-crash/) by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 34 on 2013-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-07-03**:
The sdf warnings are ok, I dont think they are causing the crash. Can you post the backtrace from the coredump? Set: `ulimit -c unlimited` in terminal, then roslaunch drcsim and wait for it to crash. A core file should be generated in `~/.ros`. Get backtrace by running `gdb gzserver` on the core file.

**Comment by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) on 2013-07-03**:
What command do I use to backtrace the core file? Is it gdb gzserver ~/.ros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This question is being tracked in a ticket:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/760/uneven-sdf-model-updates-cuase

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Jeang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/349/david-jeang/) on 2013-07-03**:
Problem has been resolved. Because of my graphics driver, I needed to convert the Sandia_hands model of the worlds files to a _cpu_lidar version to prevent it from crashing